# Как ограничить размер выплывающего списка в элементе input type="search"

Tags: html, search, dropdown

В HTML форме, для заполнения использую элемент  к которому прикручен список из 1000 элементов по которому происходит поиск требуемого элемента. и при поиске в данном поле естесственно выползает весь этот список элементов. Есть ли возможность каким-либо способом ограничить размер этого выпадающего списка, скажем до 3-5 строк. или проводить поиск только при вводе 3-х символов, пробовал играться с атрибутами minlength и прочее, но похоже что сам тег  не поддерживает такие вещи.
В глубине души догадываюсь что решение не очень (слишком грузит страницу) но пока выхожу из тех знаний которые есть

Comment: список из 1000 items это как то неудобно. может лучше через ajax отправлять на сервер запрос со значениями, что уже ввел пользователь и с сервера возвращать столько items сколько нужно?

Comment: Думаю что лучше, но по ходу обучения выбрал пока данный вариант. если ткнете носом на тутор или технологию буду примного благодарен, в форме несколько таких полей, не особо хочется для каждого поля гонять запросы на сервер.

Comment: нет необходимости подгоднять под каждый из списков. достаточно одного ендпоинта куда идут запросы с 2мя параметрами : тип вашего поля и введенная пользователем строка, возвращается массив строк. Я бы так сделал.

Comment: За ajax спасибо, WEB только учу (да и javascript признаться не знаю) буду копать в этом направлении.

Comment: для начала стоит определится на чем присать сервер. node.js, asp, php ... вариантов масса

Comment: Серверная часть написана на spring.